# How to store object in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code:

```
localStorage.setItem("ActiveDataOfpModel", iHandle.find("ul li.pModel.active"));
```

When i check "ActiveDataOfpModel" value in console i get "[object Object]".
How can i store the actual object in "ActiveDataOfpModel" and retrieve its properties. i.e. i want to do the following:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem("ActiveDataOfpModel").attr("data-id")
```

i did try

```
var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ActiveDataOfpModel")).attr("data-id")
```

but its not working

Comment: You can only store serialised object in the localStorage

Comment: localStorage only accepts strings/serialized Objs., you should use `JSON.stringify()` in the before set it to storage

Comment: I think you are trying to store a DOM element, you cannot do that. What you need to do is extract whatever you want to store eg. data ID and store only this, instead of the whole DOM element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only store strings in local storage.

You can encode simple objects as JSON (they must contain only JSON data types such as objects, numbers, and strings) as a string using `JSON.stringify(someObject)`.

> var value = JSON.parse(localStorage

… and that is how to convert the JSON back to an object afterwards.

---

Your code `iHandle.find("ul li.pModel.active")` implies you are not dealing with a simple object though. That is something I would expect to return a DOM element or something akin to it.

You would need to extract the data you care about from it, store that in an object, store that in the JSON and then the localstorage, and write more code to convert the simple data back in to the full object when you pull the data out afterwards.

Comment: iHandle.find("ul li.pModel.active") would return a jQuery object

Comment: @WaleedNaveed — I refer you to the last two paragraphs of the answerw.

Comment: thanks @Quentin . .  got my issue resolved with your last two paragraphs

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
Convert it to String before saving to LocalStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Convert back to JSON object, when reading from LocalStorage

```
data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key');
```